# How do I find the x and y position given a latitude and longitude coordinate?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, spherical-trigonometry

I am building an app that allows me to track the user's position inside a building. For this I use GPS and an image of the floor plan.

I have the latitude and longitude of each of the four corners and I now want to work out what the x and y position is in the image based on the GPS coordinate I receive.

I have provided an image to make this a lot clearer:

[Click here - don't have enough rep yet :(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0K0Eu.png)

I've tried many things so far, but this one came the closest:

Find the range between top left (min lat/lon) and bottom right (max lat/lon):

- lonrange = |minLon - maxLon|
- latrange = |minLat - maxLat|

Calculate the scale factors for pixel per degree:

- scalex = width / lonrange
- scaley = height / latrange

Now get pixel positions:

- x = (currentLon - minLon) * scalex
- y = (currentLat - minLat) * scaly

What I've done above is kinda accurate when the lat/lon point I'm trying to convert is somewhere directly between the topLeft and bottomRight of  the image but gets wildly inaccurate the more I deviate towards the other corners.

I think it's probably because of how rotated my image is compared to the map but I don't know how to account for it (I don't even know how much it's rotated angle wise).

Any help would be appreciated!

Note: also I apologise if my tags are inaccurate! I'm not very well versed in terms of what is what in maths.

Comment: If you know the corners you can calculate the distance from the point to each edge, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53147219/3871028) If some distance is greater than the length of a side edge then the point is out.

Comment: @Ripi2 Hey, how would I go about getting an actual pair of x and y coords on the image using those distances? That's what I'm actually trying to do.

Comment: In the link I provided, look for `OA`, or `OB` calculations at `main()`.Due to `O` is the center at (0,0,0) `OB` means the x,y,z coordinates of point `B` in a cartesian system centered at `O`. But you better work with "great-circles" and distances point-circle, as the link shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I've found my own solution with the help of my university professor.

I've used this solution for the building I've described above, and as the distances I am working with are quite small, I'm ***not*** taking the Earth's curvature into account.

First, we [define](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sllzV.jpg):

- the top left corner of the image as $c(0,0)$, the top right as $c(width,0)$, bottom left as $c(0,height)$ and the user’s position $u(x,y)$;
- the 3D points of each of the previously defined corners $C(0,0)$, $C(width,0)$ and
  $C(0,height)$, as well as the 3D point for the user’s location $U(x,y)$;
- three 3D vectors $U$, $V$ and $W$. The vector $U$ is the vector from $C(0,0)$ to
  $C(0,height)$, the vector $V$ is the vector from $C(0,0)$ to $C(width,0)$ and the vector $W$ is the vector from $C(0,0)$ to the user’s position $U(x,y)$;
- the distances $a1$ and $a2$ we multiply by the width and height of the image
  respectively to get our pixel coordinates.

Then, we outline the translation process:

1. measure the latitude and longitude of each of the defined corners;
2. convert each latitude and longitude into radians and calculate the 3D points $C(0,0)$, $C(width,0)$, $C(0,height)$ and $U(x,y)$, where $p$ and $P$ represent any points and 3D points respectively:
   $$
   \begin{align*}
           P_x &= \cos Lat(p) \cdot \cos Lon(p)\\
           P_y &= \cos Lat(p) \cdot \sin Lon(p)\\
           P_z &= \sin Lat(p)
       \end{align*}
   $$
3. calculate the vectors $U$, $V$ and $W$:
   $$
   \begin{align*}
           U &= C_{(0, height)} - C_{(0, 0)}\\
           V &= C_{(width, 0)} - C_{(0, 0)}\\
           W &= U_{(x, y)} - C_{(0, 0)}
       \end{align*}
   $$
   which leaves us with the following simultaneous equations to solve (as we are not using altitude, $z$ can be ignored):
   $$
   \begin{align*}
           W_x &= a_1 \cdot U_x + a_2 \cdot V_x \\
           W_y &= a_1 \cdot U_y + a_2 \cdot V_y
       \end{align*}
   $$
4. solve the simultaneous equations using Cramer's rule with matrices and their determinants:
   $$
   \begin{align*}
           D &= {\det \begin{bmatrix} U_x & V_x \\ U_y & V_y\end{bmatrix}} \qquad 
           D_x &= \det \begin{bmatrix} W_x & V_x \\ W_y & V_y\end{bmatrix} \qquad 
           D_y &= {\det \begin{bmatrix} U_x & W_x \\ U_y & W_y\end{bmatrix}}
       \end{align*}
   $$
5. calculate your pixel coordinates:
   $$
   \begin{align*}
           x &= width \cdot {D_x \over D} \\
           y &= height \cdot {D_y \over D}
       \end{align*}
   $$

This is the solution I have used in my project to turn latitude and longitude into pixel coordinates.

Source: My dissertation.

Answer (score 0):

Using $x$ and $y$ coordinates is a method to describe a position in a plain. However, the earth is not a plane. Therefore, you need to use a projection to project the points, described as lat-lng-values on a reference ellipsoid, to points on a map. Many different map projections are known, each of them with different properties. The first step is to choose one projection that suits your need. For example, you could use [UTM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system) projections.

After you projected your coordinates onto the map, all you have to do is to perform a rotation (which can be achieved by applying a $2\times 2$ rotation matrix to a point) and translation (which can be achieved by adding a vector).

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer but I'm a bit dim-witted haha. Would projection actually be necessary when the area the building covers is tiny? I'd assume that the spherical nature of the Earth would have very little effect here. Also, I'm not exactly sure what I'd be projecting - the lat/longs to the pixels on my image? I'm not sure how I'd be translating and rotating anything as I have no idea what the rotation angle even is.

Comment: Yes, I think projection is necessary. The reason for this is the following: Imagine two points, one with lat=0°, lng=0° and lat=0°, lng=1°. These points differ by a longitude of 1°, which is a certain length in meters. Now imagine two points with  lat=45°, lng=0° and lat=45°, lng=1°. These points also differ by a longitude of 1°, but their distance in meters is much shorter. Hence, the scale factors you proposed will most likely not work as you expect them to.

Comment: After you performed the projection, getting the rotation angle is simple: For example, you can take a look at the vector from "top left" to "top right" (both in x-y-coordinates) and calculate the angle between this vector and vector $(1,0)$.